# obtain the values from a checkboxgroup only once in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have made the following program:

ui.r

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
    mainPanel(
    textOutput("text1"),
    checkboxGroupInput("checkGroup", 
                       label = h3("Alternatives"), 
                       choices = list("A" = 1, 
                                      "B" = 2, 
                                      "C" = 3,
                                      "D" = 4),
                       selected = NULL),
    actionButton("action", label = "Next")
    )
))
```

server.r

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  observe({
    if(input$action>0 & input$action<=2){
      valores<-renderText({
        input$checkGroup
      })
      data<-unlist(strsplit(valores(), split=" "))
      print(data)
    }
  })
})
```

I have managed to capture the values selected and put them into a vector, so I have solved an issue I got before.

The problem that I have now is that all the time it outputs which values I select or deselect from the checkbox groups, but I would like to only capture the last values selected after I press the Next button.

Any help? I have checked the documentation, but it is pretty scarce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found in: http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/shiny/docs/isolate

that it was possible to isolate a group of sentences, so the following works nicely:

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  observe({
    if(input$action>0 & input$action<=2){
      isolate({
        values<-renderText({
          input$checkGroup
        })
        data<-unlist(strsplit(valores(), split=" "))
        print(data)
      })
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to skin that cat.

We use `isolate` and `reactive` with the `actionButton` to ensure nothing is evaluated until the button is hit. By isolating the input itself from any further formatting we can call it any number of times for any purpose. Note that without the isolate it will evaluate as the inputs are changed.

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # store as a vector to be called wherever desired
  # evaluated whenever inputs change
  datasetInput <- reactive({
    perm.vector <- as.vector(input$checkGroup)
    perm.vector
  }) 

  # call as a text output
  output$textOut <- renderText({
    input$action # makes sure nothing moves till the button is hit
    # isolate prevents datasetInput from reactively evaluating
    isolate(datasetInput()) 
  })

  # call in a different place as a data table output
  output$dataTableOut <- renderDataTable({
    input$action # makes sure nothing moves till the button is hit
    isolate(df <- data.frame(inputs = datasetInput()))
    df   
  }, options = list(
    lengthMenu = list(c(5, 15, -1), c('5', '15', 'All')),
    pageLength = 15)
  )

})
```

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput("checkGroup", 
                         label = h3("Alternatives"), 
                         choices = list("A" = 1, 
                                        "B" = 2, 
                                        "C" = 3,
                                        "D" = 4),
                         selected = NULL),
      actionButton("action", label = "Next")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      h4("Print as text"), textOutput("textOut"),
      h4("Print as data table"), dataTableOutput("dataTableOut")
    )
  )
))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks @mkemp6, but I cannot get rid of the line if(input$action>0 & input$action<=2) because I will need to count how many clicks I have made for another part of my app. Also, the value of data that contains a vector of what options have been selected I need it to be stored in a variable; not to be shown on the user interface.

Comment: @Little, you did not specify that in your original post so it was not included, but you are more than capable to put it back in. The value of the data can be called with `datasetInput()` anywhere, it will be in a vector object... I am merely displaying for an example